# Does $\operatorname{Tr}( (A+B)^ \dagger A) \leq k + \frac{1}{\lambda_{k+1} (B)}\operatorname{Tr}(A)$ for $A$, $B$ sdp and $k \in \mathbb N$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, positive-semidefinite, generalized-inverse

Whare $\dagger$ stands for the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse and $0 \leq \lambda_1(B) \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_n(B)$ stand for the eigenvalues of $B \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$.

The proof for the same inequality when $B$ is invertible goes as follows.

> For $A,B \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ both positive definite matrices.
>   First you show that for $D = B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ \begin{equation} 
> > \operatorname{Tr}((A + B)^{-1}A ) = \operatorname{Tr}( (D+I)^{-1}D ).   \quad \quad \quad(1)
> > \end{equation} Since $(D+I)^{-1}D = I - (D+I)^{-1}$  it follows that
>   $0 < (D+I)^{-1}D < I$.
>
> Since $(D+I)^{-1}D$ and $D$ have the same eigenvectors and it's easy
>   to see that $(D+I)^{-1}D  < D$.
>
> Now, if $v_1 \ldots v_n$ form an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of
>   $B$ with $0 < \lambda_1 \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_n$ their associated
>   eigenvalues. we get \begin{align*}  \operatorname{Tr}((A + B)^{-1}A ) & =
> > \sum_{i=1}^{n} v^t(D+I)^{-1}D v \\
> >                     & \leq k + \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} v^t D v \\
> >                     & = k +  \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \frac{1}{\lambda_i} v^t A v \\
> >                     & \leq k + \frac{1}{\lambda_{k+1}} \operatorname{Tr}(A) \end{align*}

I am having trouble to reproduce this idea when $B$ is not invertible. To prove (1) you first note that

\begin{align*}
(A + B)^{-1}A & = \left(B^{1/2}(B^{-1/2}A B^{-1/2} + I)B^{1/2}\right)^{-1}A \\
              & = B^{-1/2}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2} + I)^{-1}B^{-1/2} A
\end{align*}
I cannot do this for the Moore-Penrose inverse. If $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ is the space spanned by the columns of A, then
$$(AB)^{\dagger} = B^\dagger A^{\dagger} \iff \operatorname{Im}( A^*A B ) \subseteq \operatorname{Im}(B) \text{ and } \operatorname{Im}( B^*B A ) \subseteq \operatorname{Im}(A) $$
Even if the previous condition hold it there is a problem because $A \neq (B^{1/2})^{\dagger} B^{1/2} A B^{1/2}(B^{1/2})^{\dagger}$.

Obviously the inequality in the question only makes sense when $\lambda_{k+1}(B) > 0$.

Comment: >what do you denote $A^\dagger$ and $\operatorname{Ran}$?

Comment: Added to the question. Thanks.

Comment: What you denote $\operatorname{Ran}(X)$ is usually denoted $\operatorname{Im}(X)$. Your notation may lead to a confusion with the rank of the matrix.